# Migrating from log4j to log4j2 below is my log4j2.properties file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, log4j2, rollingfileappender

The log4j2 is working as i expected but in case if the file size reaches 5kb i need the new file to generate with indexed suffix i.e abclogs.log.1, but in my case the files are generating in my local directory when i run the project locally but if i deploy the same on the tomcat server the new file dynamic creation on reaching the size limit is not happening, so please suggest me with any solution.
Thanks in advance!!!

```
######LOG-1######
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = C:/Users/User/Desktop/logs/abclogs.log
appender.rolling.filePattern =C:/Users/User/Desktop/logs/abclogs.log.%i
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5.10c %-5p {%-30m}%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=5KB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5
 
logger.rolling.name = Logger1
logger.rolling.level = info
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

######LOG-2######
appender.rolling1.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling1.name = RollingFile1
appender.rolling1.fileName = C:/Users/User/Desktop/logs/xyzlogs.log
appender.rolling1.filePattern =  C:/Users/User/Desktop/logs/xyzlogs.log.%i
appender.rolling1.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling1.layout.pattern = %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5.10c %-5p {%-30m}%n
appender.rolling1.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling1.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling1.policies.size.size=5KB
appender.rolling1.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling1.strategy.max = 5
logger.rolling1.name = Logger2
logger.rolling1.level = info
logger.rolling1.additivity = false
logger.rolling1.appenderRef.rolling1.ref = RollingFile1
```

Comment: Did you check the permissions on `C:\Users\User\Desktop\logs`? Tomcat as Windows service usually runs as `LocalService`, with very limited permissions.

Comment: It is working now after changing the permissions, thanks a lot...